# How do I make a custom pop up for when I click on an asp table element?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp-classic

I have a table I've dynamically created, and I want to make it so that I see a pop up with a custom image, along with some text taken straight from the table element.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is an open ended question and we may not know what your skill set is. The answer may be as easy as saying "Lookup how to use jquery or css"

Comment: can you pls show your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the limited context you provide, I can't give you a complete solution, but I can at least outline a way to get it running:

- Use jQuery and jQueryUI.
- Bind a jQuery click event handler to the element.
- Use a jQueryUI Dialog to display the popup.

Comment: Thanks, I just stumbled upon using JQuery (i'm mostly a desktop programmer). 

How would I bind it exactly?